# How to set restrictions in Manipulate parameters?

Tags: manipulate

I´m trying to insert the typicall 3 variables for probability, with the restriction x+y+z=1

How can I insert this values in a Manbipulate

I try

```
Manipulate[x*y*(1-x-y), {x, 0, 1 - y}, {y, 0, 1 - x} ]
```

but when I move x,  y is moving without I want it.

Comment: You haven't specified z?

Comment: is not neccesary, because x+y+z=1, and if you set x and y, the z can only have one unique value.

Comment: When you move x, y is not moving, the upper bound for the slider is moving and therefore the position of the slide, but not the value of y.

Comment: yes. it´s true. and how could I do to don´t move the position of the other slide?

Comment: If you don't specify z practically x and y are independent because any two values of x and y satisfy your conation x+y+z=1. If this is the case, you do not need to set a varying upper limit of manipulate . just give them and fixed number.

Comment: What Algohi is saying is that if there isn't an additional constraint like for example $z>0$ then the equation $x+y+z=1$ is always true for any $x$ and $y$ as long as you haven't specified $z$. Do you also have a constraint on the individual variables?

Comment: ok. Could be true, z may be a complex number, I know or negative values, it´s True, but In the starting question I talk about the typicall conditinons for probability, yes I´m only interested in the z>0 alues, and < in the real numbers.

Answer (score 3):

As it has been pointed out in the comments this question doesn't make sense as it is. If we add the contraint $z>0$ it sort of makes sense so I'll post a solution based on that. <s>As far as I know it's not possible to do this with `Manipulate`</s> but if you roll your own interface it is possible thanks to the second argument of `Dynamic` (I refer to the documentation for details.)

```
DynamicModule[{x = 0, y = 0},
 Column[{
   Slider[Dynamic[x, If[(1 - # - y) > 0, x = #] &], {0, 1}],
   Slider[Dynamic[y, If[(1 - x - #) > 0, y = #] &], {0, 1}],
   Dynamic@TableForm[{
      {"x", "y", "z", "x y (1-x-y)"},
      {x, y, (1 - x - y), x y (1 - x - y)}
      }]
   }]
 ]
```

**EDIT:** As WReach pointed out in the comments there *is* a way to do this with `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
 x y (1 - x - y),
 {{x, 0}, Slider[Dynamic[x, If[(1 - # - y) > 0, x = #] &], {0, 1}] &}, 
 {{y, 0}, Slider[Dynamic[y, If[(1 - x - #) > 0, y = #] &], {0, 1}] &}
 ]
```

Comment: +1 You can embed your sliders within a `Manipulate` like this: `Manipulate[x*y*(1-x-y), {{x, 0}, Slider[...]&}, {{y, 0}, Slider[...]&}]`.

Comment: @WReach Thanks, I incorporated it in the answer.